# Don't know how to manage in laravel this database reality

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this tables:

```
 *admins*      *places*       *grants*
 id_admin      id_place       id_grant
```

Each Admin has 0-N Place. Each Place has 0-N Grant. So we have:

```
*admin_place*   *grant_place*
 id_admin        id_place
 id_place        id_grant
                 id_grant_place(this one has an autoincremental id)
```

Now what I want to do is that, each Admin could have 0-N of those grant_place. So I have a table:

```
*admin_grant_place*
 id_admin
 id_grant_place
```

How do I express this in my Laravel app?

Thank you,

Comment: show us your code you've done so far to make people easier to help you out

Comment: I didn't code anything 'cause I dont know how to manage it. Its just MySQL tables

Comment: you said you have models how you don't have code. Anyway you may use withPivot method search in laravel docs in many to many relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but a good readthrough of the Eloquent relationships documentation should have you moving in the right direction

Read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships